# Remove the plotted offset period from the chart

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm plotting a EMA on the chart using plot().
With this I'm using an offset.
Is it possible to purge / remove the drawn offset from the chart?

[remove the bit in the box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EOhh.png)

```
close_ema = ta.ema(close, length)
plot(close_ema ? close : na, color=color.new(#ffffff, 0), title='Median', offset=7)
```

tried `not barstate.islast ?` but it still plots the ema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an offset in this case. You can achieve the desired result with the [history-referencing operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Operators.html#history-referencing-operator).

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

close_ema = ta.ema(close, 20)
plot(close_ema ? close : na, color=color.new(#ffffff, 0), title='Median', offset=7)
plot(close[7], "EMA", color.blue)
```

[image]

Btw. your use of `close_ema ? close : na` makes no sense. This will simply plot the close price.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
The plot line is messed up by a copy-paste-edit action on my end.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you!